# Inserting To Table With Auto Increment MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert, ddl

Let's say I have created the following dimension table:

```
create table schema1.DOMAIN (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(10)
);
```

And I have a table of logs with records where DOMAIN_NAME is a column.  My goal here is to write an insert statement that will populate this dimension table with values for DOMAIN_NAME, but only when they don't already exist.  For example:

```
INSERT INTO schema1.DOMAIN (ID, DOMAIN_NAME)
select distinct DOMAIN_NAME from LOGS l where not exists (select 1 from schema1.DOMAIN d where d.domain_name = l.domain_name);
```

I haven't actually run this on a MySQL db yet, but I have the following questions:

1. Notice I didn't supply a value for the ID column in schema1.DOMAIN for the insert.  Does this matter?  If it's not supplied, will it simply auto-increment the primary key? Or will it throw an error?  Is there a way to avoid supplying this ID and have it auto-increment automatically? This is the desired behavior for me.  What is the best way to do this?
2. Is there a more performant way to do this?
3. I want this to work whether schema1.DOMAIN is empty or already has records and we are dumping parsing a log for a new value.  Are these two objectives not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The query you wanted to write - I just removed `id` from the list of columns for `insert`: it will auto-increment automatically for every insert:

```
insert into schema1.domain (domain_name)
select distinct domain_name 
from logs l 
where not exists (select 1 from schema1.domain d where d.domain_name = l.domain_name);
```

You could also use the `insert ... on duplicate key` syntax. This requires defining a unique constraint on the `domain` column:

```
create table schema1.domain (
    id int auto_increment primary key not null,
    domain_name varchar(10) unique
);
```

Then you can do:

```
insert into schema1.domain (domain_name)
select distinct domain_name from logs l 
on duplicate key update domain = values(domain)
```

When a `domain` that already exists in the table is met, the query goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, where a dummy operation is performed.

Comment: In the first insert statement, if a new domain_name is encountered, it will simply auto-increment the ID column and I don't have ti supply it?

Comment: @ben890: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

1.Notice I didn't supply a value for the ID column in schema1.DOMAIN for the insert. Does this matter? If it's not supplied, will it simply auto-increment the primary key? Or will it throw an error? Is there a way to avoid supplying this ID and have it auto-increment automatically? This is the desired behavior for me. What is the best way to do this?

**Ans. 
INSERT INTO schema1.DOMAIN (DOMAIN_NAME)
select distinct DOMAIN_NAME from LOGS l where not exists (select 1 from schema1.DOMAIN d where d.domain_name = l.domain_name);**

2.Is there a more performant way to do this?

**Ans. Left outer join would perform better**

3.I want this to work whether schema1.DOMAIN is empty or already has records and we are dumping parsing a log for a new value. Are these two  objectives not compatible.

**Ans. Seems compatible**